# Problem in using group by statement in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am not able to group by table which has all the values same but has two rows. I am not understanding what is the reason behind that.

After running this query i am getting the table below and i want to group the table along the LOT_No.

```
SELECT 
  c.LOT_NO LOT_NO
, (4-(DECODE(c.qty1,0,1,0) + DECODE(c.qty2,0,1,0) + DECODE(c.qty3,0,1,0) + DECODE(c.qty4,0,1,0))) NON_ZERO_QTY
, count(c.lot_no) over () as LOT_COUNT
FROM 
 CIM.QLDT_6001 a 
, CIM.PART_LOT_TBL b 
, CIM.JR_QTY_DETAIL_TBL c 
WHERE 
c.lot_no = 'F-AJR-111026-603'
AND 
a.val01 >= 100 
AND 
b.lot_no = c.lot_no
AND 
a.lot_no like '%' || b.old_lot_no || '%'
```

TABLE :

```
     LOT_NO       NON_ZERO_QTY  LOT_COUNT
F-AJR-111026-603      3             2
F-AJR-111026-603      3             2
```

Now when i am trying to Group by LOT_No, i am getting below error.

```
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 19 Column: 10
```

I also tried to take all columns from SELECT statement, but then i got this error

```
ORA-00904: "LOT_COUNT": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 19 Column: 34
```

I am totally confused what is going on.
Can anyone please help.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Can you also add the schema for the 3 tables and what you expect as the output table schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your query.

- `group by c.lot_no` is required
- Second expression in `SELECT` must be wrapped in `SUM` aggregate function. (change the expression of `CASE` statement according to requirement)
- Always use the standard ANSI-join. (Recommended)

Check the below solution:

```
SELECT 
  c.LOT_NO LOT_NO
, SUM(CASE WHEN (4-(DECODE(c.qty1,0,1,0) + DECODE(c.qty2,0,1,0) + DECODE(c.qty3,0,1,0) + DECODE(c.qty4,0,1,0))) > 0 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NON_ZERO_QTY
, count(c.lot_no) as LOT_COUNT
FROM 
 CIM.QLDT_6001 a 
JOIN CIM.PART_LOT_TBL b ON a.lot_no like '%' || b.old_lot_no || '%'
JOIN CIM.JR_QTY_DETAIL_TBL c ON b.lot_no = c.lot_no 
WHERE 
c.lot_no = 'F-AJR-111026-603'
AND a.val01 >= 100 
GROUP BY c.LOT_NO
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error

```
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
```

Says that the column you want to group by on, is found in multiple table in the query. What you need to do is prefix it with the alias of the correct table.

```
group by c.LOT_NO
```

But that will give you another error

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

because the second line in the select clause doesn't have a group function. At a first glance, you are looking for sum(). But that depends on you use-case ofcourse.

```
(4-(DECODE(c.qty1,0,1,0) + DECODE(c.qty2,0,1,0) + DECODE(c.qty3,0,1,0) + DECODE(c.qty4,0,1,0))) NON_ZERO_QTY
```

example:

```
SUM( (4-(DECODE(c.qty1,0,1,0) + DECODE(c.qty2,0,1,0) + DECODE(c.qty3,0,1,0) + DECODE(c.qty4,0,1,0)))) NON_ZERO_QTY
```

Comment: I tried this also GROUP BY c.LOT_NO  ;    Error: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: If that still gives the same error.. I bet there is another column in the query without being prefixed with the correct alias. But I think you 're encountering the ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: I don't know, i couldn't found any. The query is same as i have posted in the question. IN your answer, what you have mentioned about sum(). Can you please elaborate.

Comment: If you want to group by on LOT_NO, what would you want to do with the values in "NON_ZERO_QTY" within the GROUP BY.. Do you want the maximum value? do you want the sum of all values? Just add a group function around the already existsing calculation sum(......)

Comment: But this changes the value of count which i don't want.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood, you are not able to `Group By` on `LOT_No` or `LOT_COUNT` and get the identifier error.
This may be because you are not using the correct reference for the column. Instead, try using the specific table reference for the query as:

```
SELECT 
  c.LOT_NO LOT_NO
, (4-(DECODE(c.qty1,0,1,0) + DECODE(c.qty2,0,1,0) + DECODE(c.qty3,0,1,0) + DECODE(c.qty4,0,1,0))) NON_ZERO_QTY
, count(c.lot_no) over () as LOT_COUNT
FROM 
 CIM.QLDT_6001 a 
, CIM.PART_LOT_TBL b 
, CIM.JR_QTY_DETAIL_TBL c 
GROUP BY c.LOT_NO;
```

Also refer: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00904.php
And, http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00918_column_ambiguously_defined.htm

**UPDATE:**

Make sure you are grouping on columns that are selected in the SELECT statement.

AFTER THE ERROR:

```
SELECT 
  c.LOT_NO LOT_NO
, MAX(4-(DECODE(c.qty1,0,1,0) + DECODE(c.qty2,0,1,0) + DECODE(c.qty3,0,1,0) + DECODE(c.qty4,0,1,0))) NON_ZERO_QTY
, count(c.lot_no) over () as LOT_COUNT
FROM 
 CIM.QLDT_6001 a 
, CIM.PART_LOT_TBL b 
, CIM.JR_QTY_DETAIL_TBL c 
GROUP BY c.LOT_NO;
```

Notice the MAX function used in `NON_ZERO_QTY` statement. You can use any other such function as per your requirement. It can be SUM(), MIN(), AVG(), etc.

Comment: I tried this and i am getting error: not a GROUP BY expression and this error is at (4-(DECODE(c.qty1,0,1,0) + DECODE(c.qty2,0,1,0) + DECODE(c.qty3,0,1,0) + DECODE(c.qty4,0,1,0))) NON_ZERO_QTY

Comment: Yup. If you want to group by on `NON_ZERO_QTY` then add it in GROUP BY statement. Else you need to group it. By that I mean grouping functions need to be used on all the columns that are not used in the GROUP BY Statement.

Comment: I have edited the post so you can get the fair idea of what I am saying.

Comment: Actually this changes the value of the count which i don't want. Thanks for your help.